# What is the command to download entire container using swift client?

Tags: openstack-swift

I am using following example command to download the container.

```
swift  -A  https://127.0.0.1:443/auth/v1.0  -U   swiftops:swiftops   -K download container_name
```

But I am not able to download the entire container. I can download only 10000 objects there. Is there any way to do this automatically. I heard about --all parameter but I am not able to understand its usage.

```
swift  -A  https://127.0.0.1:443/auth/v1.0  -U   swiftops:swiftops   -K download container_name -a
```

It was giving me an invalid parameter usage exception.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Did you try adding `-all` to the command you've shown?

Comment: Yes but its giving an error . In the documentation they have mentioned its usage saying that can be used when downloading entire account.

Comment: I don't see any mention of trying it or an error when doing so in your question.

Comment: ken, I have used this command swift  -A  https://127.0.0.1:443/auth/v1.0  -U   swiftops:swiftops   -K download container_name -a

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add the details there (including the error message you receive). And my name is Ken. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using argument or paramter -m with the container name can download entire container. Below is the updated command.

```
swift  -A  https://127.0.0.1:443/auth/v1.0  -U   swiftops:swiftops   -K download container_name -m container_name
```